# Read Latitude and Longitude from a GeoJSON file, and then display each lat-long as a marker with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, font-awesome

I'm new to Javascript and hence I'm a little lost. I am able to read from a GeoJSON file; however, I do not understand how to iterate through the file to get the Lat-Long of the points, and then display those points as markers in Leaflet. I am hoping to also use the plugin Awesome Markers (based on font-awesome, for Leaflet)

This is a sample of my GeoJSON file:

```
    { "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
         { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Street Nam": "Aljunied Avenue 2", " Block": "118 Aljunied Avenue 2", " Postal Co": "380118", " Latitude": 1.320440, "Longitude": 103.887575 }, 
           "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 103.887575, 1.320440 ] } }
      ,
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Street Nam": "Aljunied Crescent", " Block": "97A Aljunied Crescent", " Postal Co": "381097", " Latitude": 1.321107, "Longitude": 103.886127 }, 
        "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 103.886127, 1.321107 ] } }
    ]
    }
```

Thank you for your attention and time =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the geojson as described in [the leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html). Specify a pointToLayer function which creates a marker with an awesome icon:

```
L.geoJson(geoJson, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, 
            {icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon( 
                 << options based on feature.properties >> 
             )});
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the file, you should have a javascript object that represents all the data in the file:

```
var geoData = JSON.parse(fileContents);
var features = geoData.features;
```

and so on. The parsed data will be converted to objects or arrays depending on whether they are key/value dictionaries or just lists. So from the above

```
var feature = geoData.features[0];
```

will get you a reference to the first feature object in the list. If you write

```
console.log(geoData);
```

and run with any recent browser you should be able to see an expandable description of the data to help make sense of it all.